# Is a 4 GB Xbox 360 enough for installing GTA V?

Tags: xbox-360, grand-theft-auto-v

I want to buy Xbox 360 but some of my friends said that it is not enough to install it.
I'm a GTA fan and I think that you guys have enough time to answer me that old question. Please tell me what I can do to install it.

Answer (score 2):

You will not be able to play GTA5 on an Xbox 360 with only a 4GB internal memory. You could get an external USB hard drive with at least 16GB and use that connected to the console to be able to play the game.

Comment: Well that's a failure on Microsofts part...

Comment: @Ben ... how's that?

Comment: Not being able to support the game without a minimum requirement, that Microsoft didn't provide...

Comment: @Ben I don't follow. If you think MS should have known the required install

Comment: Size of a game not to come out for two years when building their sku and that it should have impacted their decision, you're an idiot. There's a reasonable workaround for the small number of people who bought the 4gb console.

Comment: It also wouldn't work on an xbox 360 without a hard drive or any internal memory at all (ie the first to come out in 2005 or whenever it was). Times change.